# PHP to pull from mySql and add to html

Tags: php, html, mysql

In need of a script to pull data from table "signatures" and then input as text into an html webpage. I am using PHP (thanks to the help of mouser) to connect and store the inputs from a form into mysql. Now i want to pull the names from the name column and have it appear in a page that shows whos signed it.

Any ideas or help. I know i will have to do a  type entry in my html code but i really need help on how to construct this. If you have the abilty to throw something together quick it would be much appreciated.

Heres and update of what I have:

HTML:

```
       <div class="pure-g">
         <div class="l-box pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-2 pure-u-lg-1-4">

            <h3> 
                <action="signget2.php" method="post" class="content-subhead">
                <?php echo $row['name'}; ?>
            </h3>
        </div>
```

PHP file signget2.php:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
function openDBConnection()
{
   $myUser = "dbuser";
   $myPassd = "****";
   $myDB = "signrevis";
   $myserver = "**.**.**.**";
   $port = 3306;

    try 
    {
         $dbConn = new PDO("mysql:host=$myserver;port=$port;dbname=$myDB", $myUser, $myPassd, array( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false));
    }
    catch( PDOException $Exception ) 
    {
         echo ("Unable to connect to database.");
         exit;
    }       
    return $dbConn;
}

function doPDOQuery($sql, $type, $var = array(), $dbname, $fetch = false)
{
    $db = openDBConnection();
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //Prepare and query are two types, please use prepare.
    if ($type == "prepare")
    {
        $queryArray = array();
        if ($var != null)
        {
            foreach ($var as $key => $queryItem)
            {
                $queryArray[$key] = $queryItem;
            }
        }
        $sth = $db->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
        $sth->execute($queryArray);
    }
    else if ($type == "query")
    {
        $sth = $db->query($sql);
    }
    else
    {
        echo ("Supplied type is not valid.");
        exit;
    }
    if (!$sth)
    {
        $error = $db->errorInfo();
        echo($error[2]);
        exit;
    }

//$fetch: set to true when you expect results, set to false (default) when you do update/delete/insert and there are no records returned. Else the records are returned through $sth->fetchAll();
    if (!$fetch)
    {
        return $sth->rowCount();
    }
    return $sth->fetchAll();        
}

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query('SELECT * FROM signatures'));

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Help Please and sorry for not posting the code at first

Comment: Please provide code.

Comment: Tis the season: Do your connects n such `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query('SELECT * FROM signatures'));` then use your `<?php echo $row['name']; ?>` inside the htmls.  Didn't double check but this should be close to working if not.

Comment: We are here to aid with specific problems that you have attempted.  This means providing code, talking about what you've tried etc.  Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: instead of down-voting your question, please allow me to tell you that the best way to learn is to get your hands dirty. Never ask for free code, that will not benefit you as a developer, that is really a bad habit, if this is just a hobby, then i guess you should be motivated enough to keep it as a hobby

Comment: added code. any help would be great. not trying to shortcut it i just need this up and running asap. busniess counts on it.

Comment: @below9k You should be using mysqli or pdo. And please avoid suggesting mysql_ functions as a solution since they are deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats kinda easy to do ! In your code you should use $row in a while loop to run it over times till we get all enteries from table. Well, to show in HTML use `echo` in that while loop with any HTML code you need. Here is a sample code

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql = "SELECT name FROM signatures";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Name : " . $row["name"]. "<br/>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

When you use this it wil result in a list of names from database !

**Edit**

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
function openDBConnection()
{
   $myUser = "dbuser";
   $myPassd = "****";
   $myDB = "signrevis";
   $myserver = "**.**.**.**";
   $port = 3306;

    try 
    {
         $dbConn = new PDO("mysql:host=$myserver;port=$port;dbname=$myDB", $myUser, $myPassd, array( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false));
    }
    catch( PDOException $Exception ) 
    {
         echo ("Unable to connect to database.");
         exit;
    }       
    return $dbConn;
}

function doPDOQuery($sql, $type, $var = array(), $dbname, $fetch = false)
{
    $db = openDBConnection();
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //Prepare and query are two types, please use prepare.
    if ($type == "prepare")
    {
        $queryArray = array();
        if ($var != null)
        {
            foreach ($var as $key => $queryItem)
            {
                $queryArray[$key] = $queryItem;
            }
        }
        $sth = $db->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
        $sth->execute($queryArray);
    }
    else if ($type == "query")
    {
        $sth = $db->query($sql);
    }
    else
    {
        echo ("Supplied type is not valid.");
        exit;
    }
    if (!$sth)
    {
        $error = $db->errorInfo();
        echo($error[2]);
        exit;
    }

//$fetch: set to true when you expect results, set to false (default) when you do update/delete/insert and there are no records returned. Else the records are returned through $sth->fetchAll();
    if (!$fetch)
    {
        return $sth->rowCount();
    }
    return $sth->fetchAll();        
}

 openDBConnection();
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query('SELECT * FROM signatures'))) {
 echo '<div class="pure-g">
     <div class="l-box pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-2 pure-u-lg-1-4">

        <h3> 
            <action="signget2.php" method="post" class="content-subhead">';
            echo $row['name'];
       echo ' </h3>
    </div>';
 }

?>
</body>
</html>
```

This code will do work for you !! You have to use while($row) whenever you want the list on any html page... Opening signget2.php will show you the list with names.

Comment: ok so im back to using the code above the edit in a file signget3.php. in the html file i have <?php include 'signget2.php';?>     Nothing is loading on the page. im sorry im so clueless on this its just not something i tend to do.

Comment: its not working. im lost.

Comment: is ur table empty ? it works fine on my system or u have having different column name rather than `name`

Comment: no there are 5 rows i made. i think im just confused on creating the folder. so everything above the edit i copied into a new php file and named it signget2.php. in the html for the page i added <?php include 'signget2.php';?>     Is that all you did to display it?

Comment: codes work fine .. there is something u missing somewhere !!! just be sure ur column name is `name` and ur mysql details are correct

Comment: server is working fine as well becuase people are signing and its being added to the db. 15 rows now

Comment: are you using the one above the edit or below and what are you adding to the html page to have it run on the page?

Comment: add code which is above edit and include that php page anywhere u want

Comment: so i have the php file working now but i cant get it to display on the website. if i go straight to the php file from the web browser it works but dont know how to make it show up on the page. What is the syntax for that? ive been looking for an hour and cant get it working.

Comment: I was running the webpage as .hmtl not .php. once i changed that it worked. thanks for the help and patience